# JAVA, NodeList XML get all the children without knowing the content of te XML

Tags: java, xml, tree, vaadin, children

I'm working with Vaadin, a Java framework.

I work with XML content and I want to make a tree with this information, but I can't know how long will be the XML content. I send a call to get the XML, but with different IP addresses.

I know how to get the child, and the next child again. But I want to automated this function, like, check how long is the XML and make a loop until the end.

Here my code for now :

```
private void getData(NodeSet data)
{
    InputStream dataXml = new ByteArrayInputStream(data.toXMLString().getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
    final DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    try
    {
        final DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
        final Document document = builder.parse(dataXml);
        final Element racine = document.getDocumentElement();
        final NodeList racineNoeuds = racine.getChildNodes();
        final int nbRacineNoeuds = racineNoeuds.getLength();

        for (int i = 0; i < nbRacineNoeuds; i++)
        {
                    //System.out.print(nbRacineNoeuds);
            //System.out.print(racineNoeuds);
            if (racineNoeuds.item(i).getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE)
            {
                final Element child = (Element) racineNoeuds.item(i);
                final NodeList racineChild = child.getChildNodes();
                final int nbRacineChild = racineChild.getLength();

                for (int y = 0; y < nbRacineChild; y++)
                {
                    if (racineChild.item(y).getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE)
                    {
                        final Element child2 = (Element) racineChild.item(y);
                        final NodeList children = child2.getChildNodes();
                        final int nbChildren = children.getLength();

                        for (int a = 0; a < nbChildren; a++)
                        {
                            if (children.item(a).getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE)
                            {

                                final Element child3 = (Element) children.item(y);

                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                        //System.out.print(child);

                //tree.setParent(racineChild, child);
            }
            /*tree.addItem(racine);
             tree.addItem(racineNoeuds);
             tree.setParent(racineNoeuds, racine);
             tree.addItem(child);
             tree.setParent(child, racine);
             tree.addItem(child2);
             tree.setParent(child2, child);
             tree.addItem(child3);
             tree.setParent(child3, child2);*/
        }
    } catch (final ParserConfigurationException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (final SAXException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (final IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Thank you !

Comment: How about using a recursive method to traverse all the children of the children of the children... until there are no more children?

Comment: Yes I was thinking about that, but I don't know how to do. Which element I have to use to make this recursive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As my answer comes rather late, I guess it's mostly for posterity :)

Indeed, as pointed out by @Morfic, a recursive method might be the simplest thing you can implement to get things done right now.

I've created a [tiny project](https://github.com/octavian-nita/so/tree/master/so-43115562) to illustrate a very basic solution. It contains a [`DataSource`](https://github.com/octavian-nita/so/blob/master/so-43115562/src/main/java/com/octaviannita/service/DataSource.java) class providing some test data and a [main Vaadin UI](https://github.com/octavian-nita/so/blob/master/so-43115562/src/main/java/com/octaviannita/ui/MainUI.java) whose content is a `Tree` being filled in by the ***recursive method you need***.

```
/**
 * If <code>parentId</code> is <code>null</code> then the <code>element</code>'s
 * name or value gets added directly under <code>tree</code>.
 */
private void loadTree(Tree tree, Object parentId, Node element) {
    if (tree == null || element == null) {
        return;
    }

    // 1. We add to the tree what's given to us as argument:

    final String itemId =
        (element.getNodeType() == Node.TEXT_NODE ? element.getNodeValue() : element.getNodeName()).trim();
    if (itemId.length() == 0) {
        return; // skip eventual white spaces...
    }
    tree.addItem(itemId); // a tree item's label defaults to its ID

    // 2. If a parent ID is also provided as argument, we set that as parent for the newly added item

    if (parentId != null) {
        tree.setParent(itemId, parentId);
    }

    // 3. We then _recursively_ add to the tree every child of the given element (if any):

    NodeList children = element.getChildNodes();
    for (int i = 0, n = children.getLength(); i < n; i++) {
        loadTree(tree, itemId, children.item(i));
    }

    // 4. Optionally we can expand an item if it has any children or force hiding the arrow if not:

    if (children.getLength() > 0) {
        tree.expandItem(itemId);
    } else {
        tree.setChildrenAllowed(itemId, false);
    }
}
```

The method first adds to the provided `Tree` an item whose label / ID is created based on the `Node`'s content or name. If a parent ID is given as well, we set that as parent for the newly added node. Then, if the given `Node` has any children, we recursively call the method for each one, providing the ID of the newly created item as parent.

This should do the trick. Having said that, there are things you should (re)consider:

1. While simple, the recursive implementation might get you in trouble if the XML is (very) large; you might then opt for an iterative implementation of the same method (usually not very difficult to obtain, once the recursive one is provided)
2. Obviously, upon first call, the `parentId` argument can / should be left `null`. Since this tends to make the code harder to understand (usually, a `null` argument is not very clear), you could overload the method with `private void loadTree(Tree tree, Node element) { loadTree(tree, null, element); }` in which you hide the ugly argument; just a bit more caller-friendly...
3. I've obviously used, directly in the UI, the XML DOM model / API -- usually not the best idea (i.e. to couple the app's UI with the low-level model); in a more involved app, we do have better models (domain model, UI model, etc.); as well, one might like to use a [HierarchicalContainer](https://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/data/util/HierarchicalContainer.html)
4. The `Tree` component does not (yet) have an equivalent in Vaadin 8; therefore, the project only works with versions of Vaadin up to (and not including) 8

Bon courage alors ;)

Comment: Thanx a lot for this answer, this will help me to change what I have done before in a better way !